# Why is JSoup timing out at random places in my code?

Tags: java, web-scraping, connection, timeout, jsoup

I am currently trying to use JSoup in Java to scrape retrosheets.org for a baseball coding project I am working on.

I perform multiple JSoup connections in my code, and some of these connections are done in a loop (therefore are executed many many times). So, in total, I'm making hundreds of connections in my program to scrape the necessary data.

The program works for ~5 seconds but then gets hung up on a connection (a different one each time). Then, when I try to access the website separately in my browser the website will not load. What could be causing this? Is there an issue with performing too many connections?

Here is an example of a connection I am performing (all connections follow this same format).

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.retrosheet.org/boxesetc/index.html").maxBodySize(0).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.3 Safari/605.1.15").get();
```

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pPUt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most definitely load protection on the target website side - it detects too many requests from same IP and blocks it for a while or throttles number of connections/requests from that IP. That's why you can't open the website in the browser as well - it's not about JSoup or Java at all, it's about connections/requests from your IP to target website being blocked/throttled.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Well, you could throttle your requests - e.g. insert delays in the code that does them. Also you could implement retries (optionally with a delay between retries as well). Also there might be a problem with a number of connections you create - JSoup will probably not reuse connections, but if you use Commons HTTPClient with a connection pooling connection manager - that one will. You could retrieve HTML via Commons HTTPClient and then use JSoup for parsing only (not using it's HTTP client capabilities). Best - do all of this (delays + retries + Commons HTTPClient for retrieval).

Comment: Here's the method to parse a String as HTML via JSoup (base URL parameter is there to allow JSoup provide absolute URLs from relative ones BTW): https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: P.S. If my answer properly addresses your problem - would you mind upvoting it and/or marking it as a correct answer? Thanks!